# Is the word "laboristo" irregular?

Tags: affixes

I have noticed the suffix "ant" which (I guess) is parallel to the English "er" suffix:

> **Paroli** - to speak
>
> **Parolanto** - speaker
>
> **Ludi** - to play
>
> **Ludanto** - player
>
> **manĝi** - to eat
>
> **manĝanto** - eater

And more...

Now, when checking the words "labori" and "laboranto", why is the first translated as "to work" and the second as "laborer"?

Logic says it should be translated as "worker". But "worker" is translated into "laboristo" and not "laboranto".

Is this irregular, or are there more words that use "ist" and not "ant" to relate to the person doing an action?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

-ant- means that someone is doing something

-ist- means that someone is doing something regularly professionally or at least in a very skillful way with lots of experience.

So:

> **Paroli** - to speak
>
> **Parolanto** - a speaking one
>
> **Ludi** - to play
>
> **Ludanto** - a playing one
>
> **Ludisto** - a professional or at least especially skilled regular player
>
> **manĝi** - to eat
>
> **manĝanto** - an eating one
>
> **labori** - to work
>
> **laboranto** - a working one
>
> **laboristo** - a professional worker

There are lots of other words with -isto-: instruisto, muzikisto, kuiristo, bakisto, purigisto, ĉasisto, fiŝkaptisto, komputilisto, kuracisto, ktp.

Comment: Got it, you explained it in a clear way! Thank you :)

Comment: _Ŝtelisto_ is another example!

Answer (score 5):

Translating is not an exact science and there isn't always a one-to-one mapping between words in Esperanto and words in English. The translations you have found will just be the interpretation by one person and don't necessarily represent an official definition. Probably the closest thing we can get to an official definition in Esperanto would be the one in PIV which is available for free online at [vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net).

There the definitions are:

> **Laboristo** Homo, kiu sin dungigas por laboro
>
> **Laboranto** Homo, kiu laboradas

And labori is:

> Uzi siajn korpajn aŭ mensajn fortojn, por produkti aĵon, plenumi taskon, atingi efikon

So perhaps with that definition a *laboranto* is just someone who does some work, which for example could be to look after their own garden and they aren't necessarily paid. Whereas a *laboristo* is specifically *dungita*, meaning they are paid.

I think this more or less matches a regular interpretation of the suffixes *-ant* and *-ist*. *-ist* implies that the individual is a professional in some respects and *-ant* just means that the person generally does the action.

This would be the same for *parolanto* and *parolisto*. The former could be used to describe a person giving a talk during a conference. It might be their first talk and they don't do it professionally, whereas calling them a *parolisto* would imply they do it often and probably get paid for it.